# Replace partial string/char in columdata of Panda dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    Name   Rating
0   ABC    Good 
1   XYZ    Good @
2   GEH    Good 
3   ABH    *
4   FEW    Normal
```

Here I want to replace in the `Rating` element if it contain `@` it should replace by `Can be improve` , if it contain `*` then `Very Poor`. I have tried with following but it replace whole string. But I want to replace only the `special char` if it present.But it solves for another case if only `special char` is present.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame() # Load with data
df['Rating'] = df['Rating'].str.replace('.*@+.*', 'Can be improve')
```

is returning

```
    Name   Rating
0   ABC    Good 
1   XYZ    Can be improve
2   GEH    Good 
3   ABH    Very Poor
4   FEW    Normal
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: `df["Rating"] = df["Rating"].str.replace("@", "Can be improve") `?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Rating": ["Good", "Good @", "*"]})
df["Rating"] = df["Rating"].str.replace("@", "Can be improve")
df["Rating"] = df["Rating"].str.replace("*", "Very Poor") 
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0                 Good
1  Good Can be improve
2            Very Poor
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be use with `regex`?

Comment: Regex : Regular Expression. Like to extract pattern within the string if it is present within string or not. `import re; re.search(r'[*@]', <string>)`

Comment: To extract the string you can use `str.extract` in pandas. That works with regex also

Answer (score 1):

You replace the whole string because `.*` matches any character zero or more times.

If your special values are always at the end of the string you might use:

```
.str.replace(r'@$', "Can be improve")
.str.replace(r'\*$', "Very Poor")
```

Comment: If the `char` might be present anywhere than?

Comment: With anywhere you mean also in the middle of a word? Are there any rules where this character can appear accept at the end of the string?

Comment: Not middle of the word but, in between words. Thanks for your edit on your answer.

Comment: Then you might use `.str.replace(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<= ))@(?= |$)', "Can be improve")` and `.str.replace(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<= ))\*(?= |$)', "Very Poor")` which used lookarounds that assert what precedes is a whitespace or the start of the string and what follows is a whitespace or the end of the string.